# Esay way to include all header files from solutions explorer Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, header-files, include-path

I want include all header files from solutions explorer like this:

[image]

without add all directories with this option:

[image]

Is there an easy way to tell VS2019 to use and link all header files from solutions explorer automatically?

Why?
If I have a lot of source code directories and in each directory are the header files... I need to add each directory manually.

Other simple Example:
[image]
The directory structure it this one:
[image]
And I need to add #include "test2.h" in "test1.c" and in this case VS cant find the header file. So the header "test2.h" is NOT where the test1.c is. Why VS dont find the header automatically by solutions explorer?

Comment: This option tells VS in which **directory** look for header files. You do not have to do it for each header file, just for each directory containing them. I sure all those headers are located in singe directory.

Comment: I smell [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), please describe why you think you need this.

Comment: If I have a lot of source code directories and in each directory are the header files... I need to add each directory manually. That is not a good way...

Comment: If you `#include` a header file from the same directory as the source file, you don't need to add it. As the dialog is named "**Additional** Include Directories", you only need to add directories not related to the sources. You rarely need to setup things here, and if, just a handful.

Comment: Please provide directory structure of problematic header file. You can paste into a question content of command `tree /F`.

Comment: So I add a better und hopefully clearer example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. There is no solution.

Possible alternatives:

1. All headers are in one place and one include path is required.
2. Or headers in the same directory like the source code files.
3. Or headers need to be include like #include "../../header.h"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VS cannot provide the way of automatically including header files in all .cpp files. If the header file and the solution are in the same path, you don't  need to add path in `Additional Include Directories`. If the header file is not in the same path with project, you only need to add the path.